# くれ behind a sentence

Tags: nuances

Does adding くれ behind a sentence make it sound more angry/irritated?I’ve heard it in a song where it said
何も言わないでくれ with an angry tone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does adding くれ behind a sentence make it sound more angry/irritated

No. At least not necessarily.

くれ is the imperative form<sup>1</sup> for くれる, meaning the subject benefits from the other's doing something. So, in terms of meaning, it adds *do it for me* or *please*.

As *please* in English can indicate irritation, くれ can be the same, but does not have to be so (it can be simple *please*).

Also note that くれ is usually masculine.

---

I never thought about it, but it is an exceptional according to [this](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1312760643) in that the continuative form is used as the imperative form.

Comment: Oooooh okay!I see!!!Thank you so much!!